# Relationship between Goldbach conjecture and Mersenne primes

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbachs-conjecture

I was reading about Mersenne primes and wondering about its connection with the Goldbach conjecture. It's conjectured that there's infinitely many Mersenne primes.

One direction is trivial, that the even integer $2^{n+1} - 2$ can be written as the sum of two (Mersenne) primes. The converse, which is the GC, might not be true. Still, I want to ask what relationship between Mersenne primes and the GC is, and if it's any significant.

Comment: Mersenne primes are very rare.  So, only very few numbers will be the sum of two Mersenne primes. There is no real connection bewteen those primes. Additionally : Why is it trivial that $2^{n+1}-2$ is the sum of two Mersenne primes ? The Goldbach conjecture states that it is the sum of two primes (but does not specify them at all).

Comment: Despite of their rareness, heuristically we can expect infinite many Mersenne primes based on the probability $\frac{1}{ln(n)}$ that a random number with magnitude approximately $n$ is prime. For Goldbach's conjecture , the heuristic is far better, and it would be a miracle if it were false.

Comment: @Peter I meant that if a prime is a Mersenne prime then $2^{n+1} - 2$ trivially satisfies one instance of GC